# Wingpanel icon visible in Plank

Tags: wingpanel, plank

A fey days ago the *Wingpanel* icon showed up in my dock, and it have been there ever since. It does not go away with reboots or anything.

Does someone have a way to hide i from the dock again?

[image: Picture of Plank]

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and type:

`pkill wingpanel` (it will kill wingpanel process, but the process should restart itself without the dock icon)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click and uncheck the 'Keep in Dock'-option.